# Goerli cannot output the smart contract address after being deployed by another smart contract

Tags: dapps, erc-721, openzeppelin, goerli, smart-contract

I deployed a smart contract called Deployer.sol that deploys other NFT smart contracts, when I deploy using the remix London testnet, I got the contract address after the deployment, but cannot get the same output when deploying on the Goerli testnet using the same source code. What did I miss ?

Here is the code:

Deployer.sol version 1

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;
 
import "./NFT.sol";
 
contract Deployer  {
    address public TobeDeployed;
    function Deployme(address _addr, address _ourAddress, address _creceiver, string memory _URI, string memory name, string memory symbol, uint256 _price, uint256 _maxsupply,uint256 _totalPerWallet) public returns(address ){
        TobeDeployed = address (new NFT(_addrname, symbol));
        return TobeDeployed;
    }
}
```

Deployer.sol version 2

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;
 
import "./NFT.sol";
 
contract Deployer  {
    NFT public TobeDeployed;
    function Deployme(address _addr, address _ourAddress, address _creceiver, string memory _URI, string memory name, string memory symbol, uint256 _price, uint256 _maxsupply,uint256 _totalPerWallet) public returns(NFT){
        TobeDeployed = new NFT(_addr, name, symbol);
        return TobeDeployed;
    }
}
```

NFT.sol contract to deploy looks like this

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Opensource
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721,Pausable,ReentrancyGuard{
     // some codes here
   
    constructor(address _addr, string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC721(name, symbol){
      
        // some codes here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just solved this by emitting an event after contract deployment :)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;
 
import "./NFT.sol";
 
contract Deployer  {
    NFT public TobeDeployed;
    event logs(address addr);
    function Deployme(address _addr, address _ourAddress, address _creceiver, string memory _URI, string memory name, string memory symbol, uint256 _price, uint256 _maxsupply,uint256 _totalPerWallet) public returns(NFT){
        TobeDeployed = new NFT(_addr, name, symbol);
        emit Logs(address(TobeDeployed));
        return TobeDeployed;
    }
}
```